# Dual space of $l^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, dual-spaces

I m taking a course in functional analysis. The book state that the dual space of $l^1$, the set of real valued absolutely summable sequence, is $l^\infty$. Can anyone explain why the dual space of $l^1$ is $l^\infty$. I read a proof online [http://math.uga.edu/~clayton/courses/608/608_5.pdf](http://math.uga.edu/%7Eclayton/courses/608/608_5.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20120617032339/http://math.uga.edu/%7Eclayton/courses/608/608_5.pdf), [new link](https://www.math.colostate.edu/%7Eclayton/courses/608/608_5.pdf)). I don't understand the correspondence between $l^1$ and $l^\infty$ they mentioned. Can some one explain more about this.

Thanks

Comment: If $y=\{ y_{j}\}_{j=1}^{\infty} \in l^{\infty}$, then there is a correspondence $y \mapsto L_{y}\in (l^{1})^{\star}$ given by $L_{y}(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}x_{j}y_{j}$ for all $x \in l^{1}$. You can show that $\|L_{y}\|_{(l^{1})^{\star}}=\|y\|_{l^{\infty}}$. So the correspondence $y\mapsto L_{y}$ is isometric. And this correspondence is a surjective linear map.

Answer (score 6):

Hint.

Step I. $\ell^\infty \subset (\ell^1)^*$. This is clear as every bounded sequence (i.e., member of $\ell^\infty$) defines a bounded linear functional on $\ell^1$.

Step II. If $\varphi\in(\ell^1)^*$, and $e_n=(0,0,\ldots,1,\ldots)\in\ell^1$, the sequence with zeros everywhere except on the $n-$position where there is an $1$, set
$$
u_n=\varphi(e_n).
$$
Then
$$
\lvert u_n\rvert=\lvert\varphi(e_n)\rvert \le \|\varphi\|_{(\ell^1)^*} \|e_n\|_{\ell^1}=\|\varphi\|_{(\ell^1)^*},
$$
and hence $\{u_n\}$ is a bounded sequence, i.e., $\{u_n\}\in\ell^\infty$.

Step III. It remains to show that $\varphi(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_nx_n$, for all $x=\{x_n\}\in\ell^1$.

Setting $x^n=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,0,0,\ldots,0,\ldots)$, we have $\|x^n-x\|\to 0$ and
$$
\varphi(x^n)=\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\varphi(e_k)=\sum_{k=1}
^nx_ku_k.
$$
Hence
$$
\Big|\varphi(x)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_nx_n\Big|\le 
|\varphi(x)-\varphi(x_n)|+
\Big|\varphi(x^n)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_nx_n\Big| \\ 
\le \|\varphi\|_{(\ell^1)^*}\|x^n-x\|_{\ell^1}+\Big|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty u_kx_k\Big|\to 0.
$$

Comment: I think $\ell^1\subset \ell^\infty$. Since $(1,1,\cdots)\in \ell^\infty$ but $(1,1,\cdots)\not\in \ell^1$

Comment: @user62498. Of course. $l^{\infty}$ contains all bounded sequences. Absolutely summable sequences (members of $l^1$) are necessarily  bounded sequences.