# Prove a function in $\ell^1$ is well-defined and continuous

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, normed-spaces

Considering $\ell^1$ with the norm $\lVert·\rVert_1$, we define the following map $ f:\ell^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with:
\begin{equation} g((x_j)_{j=1}^\infty)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty (-1)^j x_j.\end{equation}
We have to show that it is well defined and continuous.

> Taking into account that absolute convergence implies convergence, I think we can say that each sequence maps to only one point in $\mathbb{R}$ and thus say it is well defined. But for continuity I've been trying with the triangle inequality and the reverse triangle inequality to try to use the definition with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that dual space of $\ell^1$ is $\ell^{\infty}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3959443/prove-that-dual-space-of-ell1-is-ell-infty) It tells you why, more generally, for any bounded sequence $(a_n)$, the map $\ell^1\to\Bbb R,\;x\mapsto\sum a_jx_j$ is well-defined, linear, and continuous. I.e. $\ell^\infty\subseteq(\ell^1)'$. (The reverse inclusion also holds but is harder.)

Comment: $g$ is linear and consitnous since $\mathbf{x}\in\ell_1$, $|\mathbf{x})|\leq\sum_n|\mathbf{x}(n)|=\|\mathbf{x}\|_1$

Comment: I don’t think ring theory is appropriate tag for this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Use the [sequential equivalence of continuity](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sequential_Continuity_is_Equivalent_to_Continuity_in_Metric_Space)

You have already seen that $f : \ell^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ where

$$f((x_j)) := \sum\limits_{j \in \mathbb{N}} (-1)^jx_j$$

is well defined.

To prove continuity through sequence, take a sequence in $\ell^1$ (a sequence of sequences!) $(x^k_j)$ for $k,j \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $x^k_j \to (a_j)$ in $\ell^1$ for some fixed $(a_j) \in \ell^1$.

What can you say about the sequence $f((x^k_j))$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$?, does it converges to $f(a_j)$?. If it does, you can say that $f$ is continuous!

Comment: But how could I prove (for the well defined part) that the function maps only onto $\mathbb{R}$ and not onto $\mathbb{C}$? Or is it not necessary?

Comment: @AlexA.G. In my answer I'm assuming $\ell^1$ is the set of all absolutely convergent sequences in $\mathbb{R}$! if you take $\mathbb{C}$ I'm not sure... it may not be well defined. Are you taking  sequences in $\mathbb{C}$ or in $\mathbb{R}$? http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-1-sequences-normed-linear-space